# SAPUI OData 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: odata, sapui5, http-status-code-405, sap-gateway

I am new to SAPUI and I'm doing some tests with OData. I built a simple project showing products of an oData service and a buttons for `create/delete/edit` a product.

When I try to create a new product or to `delete/update` it I got:

> POST MyUri.../OData/OData.svc 405 (Method Not Allowed).

**This is my browser console:**
[image]

My files:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />

  <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table"
                data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
  </script>
  <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

  <script>
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc/");
   /* var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("https://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/"); */
   /*  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel("http://localhost:8080/odata/DemoService.svc/"); */
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

    var aColumn1 = [
      new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({
          text: "ID"
        })
      }),
      new sap.m.Column({
          header: new sap.m.Label({
            text: "Name"
          })
        }),
      new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({
          text: "Description"
        })
      }),
      new sap.m.Column({
          header: new sap.m.Label({
            text: "Release Date"
          })
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Label({
              text: "Rating"
            })
          }),
          new sap.m.Column({
              header: new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Price"
              })
            }),
      new sap.m.Column({
        header: new sap.m.Label({
          text: "Supplier"
        })
      })
    ];

    var oTemplate1 = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      cells: [
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{ID}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{Name}"
          }),
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{Description}"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{ReleaseDate}"
          }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{Rating}"
          }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "{Price}"
          }),
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{Supplier/Name}"
        }),
      ]
    });

    var oTable1 = new sap.m.Table({
      id: "table",
      columns: aColumn1
    });
    oTable1.bindItems({
      path: '/Products',           
      parameters:{expand : 'Supplier'},
      template:oTemplate1
    });

    console.log(oTable1);

    var page = new sap.m.Page({
      id: "page",
      title: "OData Web App",
      showNavButton: false,
      content: [oTable1]
    });

    var app = new sap.m.App();
    app.addPage(page);
    app.placeAt("content");
  </script>

</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

***Product.controller.js*** (I tried different uri)

```
sap.ui.controller("products.Product", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf products.Product
*/
    onInit: function() {

//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc");
//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(k42qhed3hw4zgjxfnhivnmes))/OData/OData.svc");
//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(blacksheep))/OData/OData.svc");
//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/http/services.odata.org/V3/(S(au3m0bej1w40a00fq1tpt540))/OData/OData.svc");
//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(3ngooq0fkelm0nublhbj01xu))/OData/OData.svc");
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(gvhowm5dxqs50fz45zzouph3))/OData/OData.svc");
        oModel.oHeaders = {
                "DataServiceVersion": "3.0",
                "MaxDataServiceVersion": "3.0"
        };

//      this.getView().setModel(oModel, "products");
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"products");

//      console.log(oModel);
    },

/**
* Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
* (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
* @memberOf products.Product
*/
//  onBeforeRendering: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
* This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
* @memberOf products.Product
*/
    onAfterRendering: function() {
        $("#formId").hide();
    },

/**
* Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
* @memberOf products.Product
*/
//  onExit: function() {
//
//  }
    mode: 0,

    resetForm: function(){
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#description").val('');
        $("#price").val('');
        $("#rating").val('');
        $("#id").val('');
    },

    create: function(){

        this.mode = 'create';
        this.resetForm();

        $("#formId").slideDown(300, function() {

//          var id = sap.ui.getCore().byId('tableId')._getRowCount();
//          $("#id").val(id);
        });

    },
    edit: function(){

        this.mode = 'edit';
        var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId('tableId');
        var selected = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
//      alert(selected);
        if(selected ==-1){
            alert("Select row");
        }else{

            $("#formId").slideDown(function(){

                var data = oTable.getModel('products').oData['Products('+ selected +')'];

                var id  = data.ID;
                var description = data.Description;
                var price = data.Price;
                var rating = data.Rating;
                var name = data.Name;

                $("#name").val(name);
                $("#description").val(description);
                $("#price").val(price);
                $("#rating").val(rating);
                $("#id").val(id);

            })
        }


    },
    removeId: 0,

    remove: function(){

        this.mode = 'delete';

        var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId('tableId');
        var selected = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
        if(selected ==-1){
            alert("Select row");
        }else{
            var data = oTable.getModel('products').oData['Products('+ selected +')'];

            this.removeId = data.ID;

            this.save();
        }

    },
    save: function(){

        var requestObj = {

                requestUri: '',
                method: '',
                headers: {
                    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata",
                    "DataServiceVersion": "3.0",
                    "MaxDataServiceVersion": "3.0",
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata"
                }
        };

        var newData={
                "odata.type": "ODataDemo.Product",
                "ID": $("#id").val(),
                "Name": $("#name").val(),
                "Description":  $("#description").val(),
                "ReleaseDate":  $("#date").val(),
//              "DiscontinuedDate": null
                "Rating": $("#rating").val(),
                "Price": $("#price").val(),

        }

        if(this.mode == 'create'){

//          var url = "proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(3ngooq0fkelm0nublhbj01xu))/OData/OData.svc";
            var url = "proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(gvhowm5dxqs50fz45zzouph3))/OData/OData.svc";
            var method = "POST";

            requestObj.requestUri = url;
            requestObj.method = method;
            requestObj.data = newData;

        }else if(this.mode == 'edit'){

            var id = $("#id").val();
//          var url = "proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(3ngooq0fkelm0nublhbj01xu))/OData/OData.svc";
            var url = "proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(gvhowm5dxqs50fz45zzouph3))/OData/OData.svc";
            var method = "PUT";

            requestObj.requestUri = url;
            requestObj.method = method;
            requestObj.data = newData;

        }else if(this.mode == 'delete'){
            var id = this.removeId;
            var url = "proxy/https/services.odata.org/V3/(S(gvhowm5dxqs50fz45zzouph3))/OData/OData.svc";
            var method = "DELETE";

            requestObj.requestUri = url;
            requestObj.method = method;

        }

        OData.request(requestObj, function() {
            sap.ui.getCore().getModel('products').refresh();
            $("#formId").slideUp();
        });

    }

});
```

***Product.view.js***

```
sap.ui.jsview("products.Product", {

    /** Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
    * In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
    * @memberOf products.Product
    */ 
    getControllerName : function() {
        return "products.Product";
    },

    /** Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
    * Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away. 
    * @memberOf products.Product
    */ 
    createContent : function(oController) {

        var oMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({

                layoutFixed: true,
                width: '300px',
                columns: 3

        });

        oMatrix.createRow(

                new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Create",
                    width: '100px',
                    press: function(){
                        oController.create();
                    }
                }),
                new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Edit",
                    width: '100px',
                    press: function(){
                        oController.edit();
                    }
                }),
                new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Delete",
                    width: '100px',
                    press: function(){
                        oController.remove();
                    }
                })

        );

        var oLayout = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm("formId",{
            title: "Product Detail",
            content: [

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "ID"}),
//              new sap.ui.commons.TextField("id",{width: '200px', editable: false}),
                new sap.ui.commons.TextField("id",{width: '200px'}),

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Name"}),
                new sap.ui.commons.TextField("name",{width: '200px'}),

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Description"}),
                new sap.ui.commons.TextField("description",{width: '200px'}),

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Price"}),
                new sap.ui.commons.TextField("price",{width: '200px'}),

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Rating"}),
                new sap.ui.commons.TextField("rating",{width: '200px'}),

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "ReleaseDate"}),
                new sap.ui.commons.TextField("date",{width: '200px', value:"2019-09-19T22:00:00"}),

                new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: ""}),
                new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Save",
                    width: '100px',
                    press: function(){
                        oController.save()
                    }
                })

            ]
        });

        //TABLE
        var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("tableId",{
            visibleRowCount: 8,
            editable: false
        });

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "ID"}),
            visible: true,
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{products>ID}"})

        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Name"}),
            visible: true,
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{products>Name}"})

        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Description"}),
            visible: true,
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{products>Description}"})

        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Price"}),
            visible: true,
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{products>Price}"})

        }));

        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Rating"}),
            visible: true,
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{products>Rating}"})

        }));



        oTable.bindRows("products>/Products")

        var ele = [oMatrix,oTable,oLayout]

        return ele;

    }

});
```

I tried different URI and I think the create function is ok...Advices?
Thank you for the help

Comment: Do the DELETE/UPDATE methods exist in your backend?

Comment: @Lumpenstein yes, CREATE/DELETE/UPDATE methods exist